# Is there a way to enforce a schema for a JSON field within a Postgresql record in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am dabbling with json fields in Postgres.  So I am using activerecord for most validation.  But, I'd like to add a json field and be able to validate that.  Is there a clean way to do this?  I guess I could always create my own validation function but it seems like there would be a better way that may take advantage of json schemas?  Has anyone had success with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "validate that"? You want to ensure that the JSON you're putting into the database is valid JSON? You want to ensure that the JSON conforms to a certain structure? Do you want Rails/ActiveRecord to perform the validation or the database? Something else?

Comment: I think they mean validate a user using the json field

Comment: I think he is talking about using JSON schema to validate that the JSON conforms to a certain structure. https://github.com/ruby-json-schema/json-schema

Comment: @muistooshort I mean to have ActiveRecord validate that the json conforms to a certain structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [json-schema](https://github.com/ruby-json-schema/json-schema) gem:

```
schema = {
  "type" => "object",
  "required" => ["a"],
  "properties" => {
    "a" => {"type" => "integer"}
  }
}
JSON::Validator.validate(schema, { "a" => 5 }) 
# => true
JSON::Validator.validate(schema, { "a" => "five" })
# => false
```

Note that this a validator in the broader sense of the term - not a validator that can be directly used with ActiveRecord.

[Writing a custom ActiveModel validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) is pretty easy though:

```
require "json-schema"
class SchemaValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    # Looks for a JSON schema as a class constant
    c = "#{attribute.upcase}_SCHEMA"
    begin 
      schema = record.class.const_get(c)
    rescue NameError => e
      # re-raise exception with a more descriptive message
      raise( 
        $!, 
        "Expected #{record.class.name}::#{c} to declare a JSON Schema for #{attribute}", 
        $!.backtrace
      )
    end
    unless JSON::Validator.validate(schema, value)
      record.errors.add(attribute, 'does not comply to JSON Schema')
    end
  end
end
```

We can then use it like so:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  FOO_SCHEMA = {
    "type" => "object",
    "required" => ["a"],
    "properties" => {
      "a" => {"type" => "integer"}
    }
  }

  validates :foo, schema: true
end
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks! One additional question. Can you make the schema dynamic? Say I have a Payment model and the json field is called split.  Is there a way to allow the keys for split to equal { split_1: 45, split_3: 56} for one instance and allow it to equal { split_2: 45, split_4: 56} (different keys)?

Comment: Yeah I guess there is. Instead of looking for a constant in the `validate_each` method you could look for a class or instance method on `record` which defines the schema.

Answer (score 2):

You could also check json at database level. As far as I know there are two libraries that validate JSONs in PostgreSQL:

- [Postgres JSON Schema](https://github.com/gavinwahl/postgres-json-schema) written in SQL
- [is_jsonb_valid](https://github.com/furstenheim/is_jsonb_valid) written in C. (disclaimer I've written the library)

Once you have installed one of them you could do:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT data_is_valid CHECK (validate_json_schema('{/*your schema here */}', my_json));
```

if you are using Postgres JSON schema, and:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT data_is_valid CHECK (is_jsonb_valid('{/*your schema here */}', my_json));
```

if you are using is_jsonb_valid.

Comment: many thanks for making the is_jonsob_valid library. Does it support the same functions as JSON Schema? Specifically adding an  `ENUM` check constraint

Comment: @mappingdom yes it does. Here you can check the tests for enum. https://github.com/furstenheim/is_jsonb_valid/blob/master/expected/enum.out